# Сколько одновременных соединений возможно с Jsoup и HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, сеть, jsoup

Написал программу, которая должна собрать все ссылки с интернета (доменные имена) в один большой список. Использую один узел для входа (liveinternet.ru) и перебираю все внешние узлы на странице, а потом перехожу с одного ресурса на другой пока неизвестные ссылки существуют. Для соединения и изъятия узлов на внешние сайты, использую `URL`, `HttpURLConnection`, `Jsoup`.

Проблема заключается в том, что по данным на август 2021 года, в интернете насчитывается 1,88 млрд сайтов [(google)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%B2+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5&rlz=1C1IXYC_ruIL944IL944&oq=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j0i512l8.2615j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). При скорости чтения 1 сайт/сек., в день можно прочитать не более 86400 узлов. То есть чтоб собрать все 1,88 млрд. понадобиться ~60 лет. Иными словами - без многопоточности никак. Запуская всё это дело в потоках, приходиться ставить паузу `Thread.sleep(200)` между запусками потоков на чтение. То есть скорость 5 ресурсов в секунду (читать лет ~12 :)) На сколько я понимаю - забивается socket; не могу понять - сколько одновременных подключений возможно? Как это узнать и где посмотреть? От чего или от кого зависит количество соединений? Это во-первых. А во-вторых, обрабатываю такой вот список ошибок (скорость 200ms) в лог файле:

```
Start: 10-10-2022 19:19:28
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Connection reset.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection reset. 
ConnectException. Connection timed out.
ConnectException. Connection timed out.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection reset.
SocketTimeoutException. Read timed out.
SocketTimeoutException. Read timed out.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection reset.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection reset. 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection reset.
Stop:10-10-2022 19:25:30
```

Увеличивая скорость, список ошибок становится больше... Как ускорить весь этот процесс? Сколько одновременных соединений возможно?

Демоверсия программы доступна для скачивания [Readme.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13UUZgjD4cN1gbqHg1oMBcoFZEexZgxbN/view?usp=sharing) [.jar файл](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18fDKh0vKWvOoI3gBouy5UpbE0jwznOyt/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: учитывая  скорость появления новых  сайтов   и предполагаю  у вас не самый быстрый в мире  компьютер,   и какая у вас операционная система ,  даже  linux   по количеству открытых  портов.   И  главное  за каой период  вы хотите  собрать  всю   информацию?

Comment: @Труфальдино Было бы здорово собрать всю информацию за пол года.

Comment: Сначал  надо  заставить  JVM  работать  с о всей памятью   на машине.  Потом  сконфигурировать  JVM для использования дискового пространства (только  java+) .  потом создать столько потоков сколько у  вас  ядер на компьютере -1.  И  вашу  ОС   тоже надо  сконфигурировать (но это  уже завистт от  ос)

Comment: @Труфальдино `создать столько потоков сколько у вас ядер на компьютере` - количество потоков на чтение не связано с количеством ядер. Я думаю этот вопрос регулирует сетевая карта и провайдер. Память на мониторе ресурсов - холодная. Процессор - да, надо помощнее...

Comment: Карта нагружена?  <b>количество потоков на чтение не связано с количеством ядер. </b> Либ о я вас не понял, либо  я сомневаюсь  . Откуда такая уверенность?  память  холодная ,  а  что  вы смтотрите  и чем?  Если  я вас правильно  услышал ваша загрузка по  сетевой карте не большая ,  так может и  надо  увелисить потребление памяти.  А давайте вместе код  посмотрим?  Может  что  увидим

Comment: `загрузка по сетевой карте не большая` - наоборот, большая! Время получения страницы -от 1 и более секунды (в зависимости от ресурса). А я запускаю по 5 потоков в секунду. Поток закрывается после того как прочитал, разобрал и записал данные. Таким образом, я захожу 1 раз на liveinternet.ru, беру 1 страницу, а потом перехожу по внешним ссылкам и беру узлы у них. За ~5мин. удалось собрать чуть больше 5000 ресурсов и 1 возврат на точку входа. То есть на liveinternet.ru я зашёл 2 раза.

Comment: Поток сначала запрашивает Header (проверятся content-type и код страницы), потом берёт файл robots.txt и загружает страницу. @Труфальдино могу отправить на почту ссылку на папку с классами в google диск. Программа на стадии разработки, поэтому в коде придётся разбираться... Многопоточность вообще сразу не планировалась.. Однако, при запуске есть GUI и проблем с понимание не должно быть :)

Comment: можете на яндекс диск или  гкгл  диск выложить ?  очень хочеться поиграться

Comment: @Труфальдино обновил вопрос. Добавил ссылки для скачивания. Исходный код (пока) не даю; надеюсь найти единомышленников (инвесторов? :) для развития проекта. Если это интересно - дайте знать. Что-то придумаем.